# Access Element in AngularJS using Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

unable to access the element using ng-model locator
PFA [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOTot.jpg)

[image]

In the image there is front end Enter Name Column in which i want to enter name and the error i am getting while using ng-model

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Posible issue is that the element could be not visible, You can put some waits using ExpectedConditions, here is full documentation https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;    
var nameColumn = element(by.model("data.iName"));
      browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.model("data.iName))), 30000, "Input element is not visible").then(function() {
                nameColumn.sendKeys("name");
         });
```